# JavaFx 2.0: Controlling the Z-Order of Stage elements

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

JavaFx 2 has built in a couple methods for controlling z-order but they are not very fine grained.  You can call toFront() or toBack().  But what if you want to insert a visual element, say, right above level 4?

Comment: According to this page: https://blogs.oracle.com/rakeshmenonp/entry/javafx_z_order_of_nodes, you can extend the Node class that implements Comparable, put instances of that in a Sequence, that you then add to a Group. They are sortable with the javafx.util.Sequences class.

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve it by getting the children `ObservableList` of the parent node and manipulate them, for instance by `add(int index, Node element)`:

```
parent.getChildren().add(4, visualElement);
```

AFAIK toFront() and toBack() are working in the same manner.